# Repeating the server name in the Win32_Service StartName report

Tags: powershell

I am trying to figure out in Powershell how to format this input example.

```
Input
SERVER0040 name                               startname              
---------- ----                               ---------              
           AGS Cash Forecasting               DOMAIN\serviceaccount
           AGS CutOffTime                     DOMAIN\serviceaccount
           AGS DL                             DOMAIN\serviceaccount
SERVER0042 name                           startname              
---------- ----                           ---------              
           AGBankImportService            DOMAIN\serviceaccount
           AGConfirmationDeliveryService  DOMAIN\serviceaccount
           AGConfirmationMatchService     DOMAIN\serviceaccount
```

To get the output as shown below.

```
Server     name                               startname                    
SERVER0040 AGS Cash Forecasting               DOMAIN\serviceaccount
SERVER0040 AGS CutOffTime                     DOMAIN\serviceaccount
SERVER0040 AGS DL                             DOMAIN\serviceaccount      
SERVER0042 AGBankImportService            DOMAIN\serviceaccount
SERVER0042 AGConfirmationDeliveryService  DOMAIN\serviceaccount
SERVER0042 AGConfirmationMatchService     DOMAIN\serviceaccount
```

Thanks for any input.
Edilberto

Comment: Please [format your code and sample input/output properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777) and please read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: what have you tried to take that input and try to put that out in format you need ?

Answer (score 0):

You are not showing your code, forcing folks to guess at this. There are several ways to format output, depending on how you are getting it in the first place. A simple idea of this is shown is below.

***Example:***

```
Clear-Host
$env:COMPUTERNAME,'nwtex01','nwtiis01' | 
ForEach {
    Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $PSItem -Class Win32_Service |
    Select-Object -Property SystemName, Name, StartName -First 3 | 
    Format-Table -AutoSize 
}

# Results
<#
SystemName Name            StartName          
---------- ----            ---------          
NWTDC01   adfssrv         NORTHWINDTRADERS\adfsadmin
NWTDC01   AdobeARMservice LocalSystem        
NWTDC01   ADSync          NORTHWINDTRADERS\sqladmin 



SystemName Name            StartName                
---------- ----            ---------                
NWTEX01   AdobeARMservice LocalSystem              
NWTEX01   AeLookupSvc     localSystem              
NWTEX01   ALG             NT AUTHORITY\LocalService



SystemName Name            StartName                
---------- ----            ---------                
NWTIIS01  AdobeARMservice LocalSystem              
NWTIIS01  AJRouter        NT AUTHORITY\LocalService
NWTIIS01  ALG             NT AUTHORITY\LocalService
#>
```

This is a very common PowerShell 101 kind of thing, with many examples in the built-in help files, and blogs all over the web.